# Problem receiving the response from a .post

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, response, .post

I tried the following query.

When I see the answer through devtools I have the following:

{status: true, info: [,…], punitorios: [4786.6, 4677.4],…}
status: true
info: [,…]
punitorios: [4786.6, 4677.4]

But I can't execute the code should be executed for true:

```
$.post('/buscarCuotas',{_token:_token,dni:dni},function(data){

    if(data.status === true)
    {
        .....
```

What can it be due to? I tried adding, 'json' at the end of the .post, but it didn't work

Comment: Is the response actually of a boolean value type, or is it a string? You may consider using data.status == true.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, the question is not clear, if you don't feel comfortable writing in english, you can ask on es.stackoverflow.com. Nicolas, la pregunta no es clara, es bastante confusa y no se identifica cual es el problema, ni que es lo que esperas conseguir. Si no te sientes comodo preguntando en ingles, intenta usar SO en español.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need to obtain a JSON data you need serialize the response, or in order to use a more updated code you can use `fetch` in where you can use

```
    fetch('URL',
    method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(dataForTheServer))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
     if(data.status === true)
        {
      ...
     }
    }).catch(errorHandler)
```